# How to debug Flutter notifications opening on iOS > 14

Tags: ios, flutter, logging, ios14

Since iOS 14.0 Flutter apps can't be [relaunched in debug mode](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60657).

So how do you get some logs while implementing `firebase_messaging` methods?

Running `flutter run --release` hides the logs from the terminal. So how do you do?

Answer (score 0):

So I got one slow way:

1. Run the app with `flutter run --release`
2. Check that some logs are showing in macOS `console` app (filter logs with 'Flutter', 'Runner' or any strings you want)
3. Then close the app, receive the notification
4. Logs appear

With this solution you can't hot-reload the app, you have to rebuild it. Mine takes 3mn to test. Not optimal but at least I've got some logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
flutter run -d 'device_id' --profile
```

This will run your app in profile mode which is similar to release mode and provides logs in console as well.